# How to pass specific key from `$data` into the nested graphql query?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, gql, gqlquery

There are publications and tags with many-to-many relations. Here's `schema.gql`:

```
input GetPublicationsDto {
  cursor: Int
  take: Int
  tagIds: [Int!]
  tagId: Int
  ...
}

input GetTagsForDto {
  tagIds: [Int!]
  tagId: Int
}

type Query {
  publications(data: GetPublicationsDto!): [Publication!]!
  tagsFor(data: GetTagsForDto!): [Tag!]!
}
```

We see that `GetPublicationsDto` extends `GetTagsForDto`.
Suppose we want to get publications by some tagId and this tag data in a single request. Here's the query:

```
query PublicationsWithTags($data: GetPublicationsDto!) {
  publications(data: $data) {
    ...PublicationEntry
  }
  tagsFor(data: $data) {
    ...TagEntry
  }
}
```

This code fails to compile. The error is `Variable "$data" of type "GetPublicationsDto!" used in position expecting type "GetTagsForDto!".`

IMHO this code has to work, but the error is clear. It wants different data to be provided to `tagsFor` query. But how to extract specific key from `$data`?

I tried

```
query PublicationsListWithTags($data: GetPublicationsDto!) {
  publications(data: $data) {
    ...PublicationListEntry
  }
  tagsFor(data: { tagId: $data.tagId }) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

It does not compile either, `Cannot parse the unexpected character "."`. What is the right way to extract key from `$data` and pass it into the `tagsFor` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TWIMC, the solution for the provided example is trivial,

```
query PublicationsWithTags($data1: GetPublicationsDto!, $data2: GetTagsForDto) {
  publications(data: $data1) {
    ...PublicationEntry
  }
  tagsFor(data: $data2) {
    ...TagEntry
  }
}
```